# php Looping through Input Items to get Min Max Value

Tags: php

I would like to find the lowest value in a array text inputs. Here is the code to output the input:

```
<input type="number" size="5" name="wholesale[<?php  echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo $variation_data['_wholesale_price'][0]; ?>"/>
```

How would i get the lowest value entered with just php? I'm not sure if this is possible, or if i need to use jQuery aswell?

Comment: show more code. The way you are generating the array. And your array.

Comment: At which point are you trying to obtain the lowest value?

Comment: @billyonecan im not, thats the question

Comment: Try the php manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Comment: I mean at which point do you wish you obtain the lowest value?

Comment: i am trying the following: <?php echo min(array($variation_data['_wholesale_price'][0]));  ?>

Comment: @danyo We need more - show your current loops/array manipulation, plus part of an array dump so we can get an idea of contents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
$array = array_map('intval', $array);
```

Use the above to get numerical values and then use something like this:

```
$min = min($array);
```

But I don't get what are you trying to do?Get teh first value in the array?loop through each?It`s vague.Show more code.